# Runtime error 1004 when assigning cell formula via vba

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, vba

From within code, based on particular criteria, I am trying to assign a formula to a particular cell.  See code

```
        For l = 8 To lEND
        lPriorNum = .Range("N" & l)
        If lPriorNum = 1 Then
            sFormula = "=ROUND(IF(AND(N" & l & "=1,K" & l & "=0),O" & l & _
            "/100*M" & l & ",(IF(AND(N" & l & "=1,K" & l & "<>0,K" & l & _
            "<M" & l & "),K" & l & ",M" & l & "))),2)"
        Else
            sFormula = "=ROUND(IF(P" & l & "=0,0,(IF(AND(N" & l + 1 & _
            "<>1,K" & l + 1 & "<>0,M" & l + 1 & ">R" & l + 1 & _
            "),K" & l + 1 & ",(IF(AND(N" & l + 1 & "<>1,K" & l + 1 & _
            "<>0,P" & l & ">0,P" & l & "<K" & l + 1 & "),+P" & l & _
            ",(IF(AND(N" & l + 1 & "<>1,K" & l + 1 & "=0,P" & l & _
            "<=0),0,(IF(O" & l + 1 & "/100*SUM(M" & l + 1 & "-L" & l & _
            ")>M" & l + 1 & ",0,(IF(O" & l + 1 & "/100*SUM(M" & l + 1 & _
            "-R" & l & ")<M" & l + 1 & ",O" & l + 1 & "/100*SUM(M" & l + 1 & _
            "-R" & l & "),(IF(M" & l + 1 & "<=R" & l + 1 & ",IF(P" & l + 1 & _
            "-K" & l + 1 & "<0,0,+M" & l + 1 & "-K" & l + 1 & ")))))))))))))),2)"
        End If            
        .Range("L" & l).Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
        ActiveCell.Formula = sFormula
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
        ' Total Payout Available
        sFormula = Range("Tot_Pay_Avail").Formula
        .Range("P" & l).Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
        ActiveCell.Formula = sFormula
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
        ' Final Dist Running Bal
        sFormula = Range("Final_Dist_RB").Formula
        .Range("Q" & l).Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
        ActiveCell.Formula = sFormula
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
        sFormula = Range("Payout_Amt_Sum").Formula
        .Range("R" & l).Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
        ActiveCell.Formula = sFormula
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"

        sFormula = vbNullString
    Next l
```

When the lPriorNum = 1, the code to populate L whatever works fine.  When the lPriorNum is not 1, the following is the formula that is in sFormula and this does not work.  I get the 1004 error:

=ROUND(IF(P9=0,0,(IF(AND(N10<>1,K10<>0,M10>R10),K10,(IF(AND(N10<>1,K10<>0,P9>0,P91,K10=0,P9<=0),0,(IF(O10/100*SUM(M10-L9)>M10,0,(IF(O10/100*SUM(M10-R9)

I've been told this formula as it's written will only work in Excel 2010 and I am testing in 2007, however, 2010 users are getting the same error when they test this.  What might be the issue with this formula or the way the syntax is written?  The cell on the spreadsheet is formatted as number with no commas and 2 decimals.  I've looked through some of the postings here and other websites but I think my question might be more specific than I might find in other postings...

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: what is the text of the error?

Comment: Application-defined or object-defined error.  It also doesn't look like I pasted the whole value of sFormula after it's been populated... which is: =ROUND(IF(P9=0,0,(IF(AND(N10<>1,K10<>0,M10>R10),K10,(IF(AND(N10<>1,K10<>0,P9>0,P9<K10),+P9,(IF(AND(N10<>1,K10=0,P9<=0),0,(IF(O10/100*SUM(M10-L9)>M10,0,(IF(O10/100*SUM(M10-R9)<M10,O10/100*SUM(M10-R9),(IF(M10<=R10,IF(P10-K10<0,0,M10-K10)))))))))))))),2)

Comment: WHat happens when you manually enter the above formula in the worksheet?

Comment: Because I am testing in 2007 (I don't actually have 2010), I get: "The specified formula cannot be entered because it uses more levels of nesting than are allowed in the current file format."  AND I have to paste it into the formula bar and not directly into the cell to get that error message at all...

Comment: Ok I tested it in 2010 and it works just fine

Comment: In 2010 the formula pasted directly into the cell will work, but beyond my limitations of 2007's error on that formula, the 2010 user is getting the same 1004 error when trying to run the macro that populates the L current cell with that formula.  I would agree that I will get that error when trying to run the code in 2007 but I want the 2010 user to be able to run this without the error.  If we are both getting this error then what part of the syntax is wrong or what should I be taking into account that I'm not, since we know the formula will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a new workbook in the 2007 version. Pasting the formula `=ROUND(IF(P9=0,0,(IF(AND(N10<>1,K10<>0,M10>R10),K10,(IF(AND(N10<>1,K10<>0,P9>0,P9<K10),+P9,(IF(AND(N10<>1,K10=0,P9<=0),0,(IF(O10/100*SUM(M10-L9)>M10,0,(IF(O10/100*SUM(M10-R9)<M10,O10/100*SUM(M10-R9),(IF(M10<=R10,IF(P10-K10<0,0,M10-K10)))))))))))))),2)` into excel 2007 works with no errors.

Pasting the same formula into a 97-2003 .xls file gives me the *Too many levels of nesting* error. note that a **converted** file will give the same issues

Comment: This worked after I created a new macro enabled 2007 workbook as suggested.  The code did not error nor did a manual paste of the formula into the cell result in an error.  I appreciate all your help!